# Excel UDF - Enumerate / Explain Inputs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm wondering how to do this since I never have been asked to do this before.

I know that if I write a UDF in Excel, I can use `Application.MacroOptions` to create a description for the function and its input parameters.

However, if, for example, you use Excel's built in `VLOOKUP()` function, for the last argument `[Range_Lookup]`, as you start typing it into the sheet, it gives you an automatic drop-down box saying:

```
TRUE - Approximate match
FALSE - Exact match
```

I'm wondering how I can add in that kind of functionality to my UDFs, so if there's an enumerated or TRUE/FALSE input, I can offer the drop-down and an explanation as to what each option will mean.

Any ideas?? (Current version = Excel 2010)

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are referring to Function Intellisense: if so there is no way anyone has yet discovered of implementing that for UDFs. 
(And yes the Excel team has been asked for this feature numerous times)

Comment: Well that just plain sucks!! :) - But thanks for, at least, helping me save time from looking around pointlessly for hours. 
I'll leave the question open for a while longer HOPING someone else might have some other input, but I'll mark your as the solution otherwise. Thanks again!!